# Problem connecting Azure DevOps on-site with Azure

Tags: azure-devops

I am trying to create a service connection from Azure Devops on premise to my Azure connection. But I get this error:

> Failed to obtain the Json Web Token(JWT) using service principal client ID.
> Exception Message: An error occurred while sending the request.

The user is owner in the subscription.

Comment: When you get this error?

Answer (score 0):

> Problem connecting Azure DevOps on-site with Azure

According to the error, it seems that the Service principal key has expired.

You could try to run below script on the Azure DevOps OnPrem machine and can verify if able to generate the access token:

[GetAccessToken.ps1](https://github.com/Ajay-MS/UtilityScripts/blob/master/Subscription/GetAccessToken.ps1)

And try to create a new service principal and service principal key to create the new service connection.

BTW, you could check if it works with Azure DevOps service when using the same service connection configuration.

Comment: I have this result:The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request.
At C:\solucion.ps1:32 char:5
+     throw $exceptionMessage
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : OperationStopped: (The remote serv...0) Bad Request.:String) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request.

Comment: @AntonioJimenez, Have you add the value for those `servicePrincipalId`, `servicePrincipalKey`, and so on in the powershell scripts? And how about create an new Service principal key?

Comment: Yes. I am add the values in the servicePrincipalId and servicePrinciaplKey

Comment: This is the result:

token_type     : Bearer
expires_in     : 3599
ext_expires_in : 3599
expires_on     : 1614771373
not_before     : 1614767473
resource       : https://management.azure.com/
access_token   : eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsIng1dCI6Im5PbzNaRHJPRFhFSzFqS1do
Why not connect my azure devops?